# JavaScript array for an image gallery with next and prev functions

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image-gallery

```js
var spanishAdventure = new Array();

spanishAdventure[0] = new Image();
spanishAdventure[0].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756508_1743696655674610_7179458580676129491_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=f16a2edf4ee735e66b6dab095b7fb43c&oe=5B6B32B3'; 

spanishAdventure[1] = new Image();
spanishAdventure[1].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26758659_1743696569007952_4447096103197624856_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=a7f015a6709fa9a26f06b07fe9782999&oe=5B6A180E'; 

spanishAdventure[2] = new Image();
spanishAdventure[2].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678421_1743695449008064_7298258449829506874_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=d8fb71ad599a0a630f4d118c1d8be6ca&oe=5B6E0AFD'; 

spanishAdventure[3] = new Image();
spanishAdventure[3].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678110_1743696009008008_4042393389305650172_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7d6afafd399c4a2d5d8f0747d59d8353&oe=5B73557C'; 

spanishAdventure[4] = new Image();
spanishAdventure[4].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756324_1743697449007864_8430059194945119796_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=5c93856d22087dbf550fc98dfd7a79ce&oe=5B5FBF15';

spanishAdventure[5] = new Image();
spanishAdventure[5].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF';

spanishAdventure[6] = new Image();
spanishAdventure[6].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26841396_1743696739007935_7256143030060966136_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=d0b9cbe4f3920af54083ea12d2d19b40&oe=5B63A5E7';
   
var imageCount = 0;
var totalImage = spanishAdventure.length -1; //array length starting from 0
var img = document.getElementById('mySlides'); //HTML img element which image will be displayed
   
function imagePrev() {
imgCount-- ;
img.src =spanishAdventure[imageCount].src;
if (imageCount < 0) {
img.src = spanishAdventure[totalImage].src;
break;
}
}

function imageNext() {
imgCount++ ;
img.src =spanishAdventure[imageCount].src;
if (imageCount > totalImage) {
img.src = spanishAdventure[0].src;
break;
}
}
```

Hi Guys,

I'm currently trying to create an image gallery using Javascript image array and functions that will be called upon to create a gallery in an image element in my original HTML file (not shown).  Do you see anything wrong with the js syntax and code for the next and previous functions as they seem to not work when called upon in the html file.  I'm a newbie so some enlightening pointers would be fab.

mySlides is the id for an HTML img element.

Cheers,

Liam

Comment: post the html code

Comment: You're incrementing/decrementing `imgCount` and you're using `imageCount` as the index.

Answer (score 1):

1. As @Titus said, change imageCount to imgCount, or vice-versa
2. Remove `break;` from `imagePrev` and `imageNext`. It's not doing anything useful.
3. Build logic to keep imageCount (or imgCount) within the range of your image array.
4. You don't need to instantiate images to store your source urls. The urls are just text, so they could be put directly into an array, like `spanishAdventure = ['urlText1', 'urlText2', ...]`

   ```js
   var spanishAdventure = new Array();

   spanishAdventure[0] = new Image();
   spanishAdventure[0].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756508_1743696655674610_7179458580676129491_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=f16a2edf4ee735e66b6dab095b7fb43c&oe=5B6B32B3'; 

   spanishAdventure[1] = new Image();
   spanishAdventure[1].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26758659_1743696569007952_4447096103197624856_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=a7f015a6709fa9a26f06b07fe9782999&oe=5B6A180E'; 

   spanishAdventure[2] = new Image();
   spanishAdventure[2].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678421_1743695449008064_7298258449829506874_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=d8fb71ad599a0a630f4d118c1d8be6ca&oe=5B6E0AFD'; 

   spanishAdventure[3] = new Image();
   spanishAdventure[3].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678110_1743696009008008_4042393389305650172_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7d6afafd399c4a2d5d8f0747d59d8353&oe=5B73557C'; 

   spanishAdventure[4] = new Image();
   spanishAdventure[4].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756324_1743697449007864_8430059194945119796_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=5c93856d22087dbf550fc98dfd7a79ce&oe=5B5FBF15';

   spanishAdventure[5] = new Image();
   spanishAdventure[5].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF';

   spanishAdventure[6] = new Image();
   spanishAdventure[6].src = 'https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26841396_1743696739007935_7256143030060966136_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=d0b9cbe4f3920af54083ea12d2d19b40&oe=5B63A5E7';
      
   var imageCount = 0;
   var totalImage = spanishAdventure.length -1; //array length starting from 0
   var img = document.getElementById('mySlides'); //HTML img element which image will be displayed
      
   function imagePrev() {
     imageCount > 0 ? imageCount-- : imageCount = 6;
     img.src =spanishAdventure[imageCount].src;
   }

   function imageNext() {
     imageCount < 6 ? imageCount++ : imageCount = 0;
     img.src =spanishAdventure[imageCount].src;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <img id="mySlides" />
   <button onClick="imagePrev()">Prev</button>
   <button onClick="imageNext()">Next</button>
   ```

Comment: The `imageCount > 0 ? imageCount-- : imageCount = 6;` line is using what's called a ternary operator, which is an abbreviated way to write if statements.

Comment: Great thanks that got it working, however in the last line in each function i used `img.src =spanishAdventure[imageCount].src;` rather than writing the whole `document.getElementById('mySlides').src =spanishAdventure[imageCount].src;` but that seemed not to work, can you think why img.src was not accepeted?  Cheers again!